# How to center text without adding space AND not altering alignment of surrounding text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

In normal text, how do I center part of a sentence (it happens to be the end of a sentence) but leave the text in the rest of the paragraph unaltered? Also, no vertical space should be added before or after the centered text.

In a word processor, I would add a new line just before the text to be centered and then "center" the text on the next line.  I tried doing things similar to this with various LaTeX commands, but nothing worked.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
This is a really long sentence as an example.  The second half of this
                               sentence should be centered.
```

Comment: Does `\centering` not yield the desired result? Do you want to keep the indentation of the first line of the paragraph?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a really long sentence as an example.  The second have of this\\
\centerline{sentence should be centered.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires manually determining where the last line of the paragraph will start. A modification to the paragraph might produce undesired results.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I didn't want to center the last line of a paragraph.  I wanted to center specific words in the text.

Comment: This still adds some vertical space for me when used inside a table cell.

Answer (score 55):

Please do not use `\centerline` if possible, it's not suitable for long text. Just patch LaTeX's `center` environment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{%
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{tightcenter}
foo
\end{tightcenter}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an improvement but for me still adds some vertical spacing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `\centerline` should not be used? What does "not suitable for long text" mean?

Comment: @Roly Adding `\unskip` after `\begin{center}` does the trick for me.

Comment: Caution! This affects the whole document.

Comment: @mhucka https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311293/centerline-ignores-page-margin this might answer your question.

Comment: @scribe I think you're right; that looks like a good reason for avoiding `\centerline`. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You could use the TeX primitives `\rightskip` and `\leftskip`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
This is a really long sentence as an example.  The last line of this
paragraph will be centered.\par
\endgroup
Another sentence that starts a new paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

The explanation of the code (as given in TeX by Topic):

> For all lines of a paragraph but the last one the stretch components
>   add up to zero so the `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` inserted are zero.
>   On the last line the `\parfillskip` adds `plus 1fil` of stretch;
>   therefore there is a total of `plus 0.5fil` of stretch at both the
>   left and right end of the line.

Comment: +1 Works without needing to know where the line breaks (though the OP didn't state this as a requirement)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina why bother?  what's wrong with `{\par\centering ...text...\par}`

Comment: There should also be a `\noindent` in front of the centered paragraph, otherwise the first line will not be completely centered.

Comment: @wasteofspace Using `\centering` will not justify all the lines of the paragraph leading up to the last line. Try putting a six-line paragraph in Gonzalo's setting vs the same in yours and note the difference in formatting.

Answer (score 14):

Just place the portion to be centered in a full-width `\makebox`.  Here are two examples in this MWE: 1) what the OP asked about, and 2) a paragraph that continues after the event.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
This is a really long sentence as an example.  The second half of this\\
\makebox[\textwidth]{sentence should be centered.}

This is a really long sentence as an example.  
This is a really long sentence as an example.  
The second half of this\\
\makebox[\textwidth]{sentence should be centered.}
This is a really long sentence as an example.  
This is a really long sentence as an example.  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It can also be solved using a pair of `hspace*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a really long sentence as an example.  The second half of this\\
\hspace*{\fill} sentence should be centered. \hspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tabular` environment, with one centred column:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    Left-justified here! \\
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Text in here is centred.
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! But that's a very bad idea for long text, isn't it?

Comment: there is a ``\\`` missing, otherwise the table will appear on the same line

Comment: Even with a preceeding `\\ ` this will not be centered on the page.  You need a `tabular*` and a width specification - but really a version of `center` is much easier.