# How to center the last line of a paragraph?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I am trying to center the last line of each paragraph to keep with an old style typesetting. I tried using the example by Gonzalo Medina in [How to center text without adding space AND not altering alignment of surrounding text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24186/how-to-center-text-without-adding-space-and-not-altering-alignment-of-surroundin/24188#24188), but instead of centering the line it sticks out into the right margin. I am still not quite sure how the code is suppose to work, and I'm guessing that using a 2 column book format also has something to do with it. Below is a sample of what I'm doing: (I apologize for the length)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,openany]{book}%Compile with xelatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Narkisim}
\newlength\iiindent \setlength\iiindent{15pt} 
\newcommand\secindent{\parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth } 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
\sloppy
\everypar{\secindent}
(ג) ויאמר אלוהים יהי אור - מלת "אמירה" בכאן להורות על החפץ, כדרך מה תאמר נפשך ואעשה לך (ש"א כ ד), מה תרצה ותחפוץ, וכן ותהי אשה לבן אדניך כאשר דבר ה' (להלן כד נא), כאשר רצה. כי כן הוא הרצון לפניו, או הוא כגון מחשבה, כמו: האומרה בלבבה (ישעיה מז ח). ואמרו אלופי יהודה בלבם (זכריה יב ה). והעניין לומר שלא היה בעמל. וכך קראו רבותינו לזה "מחשבה". אמרו (ב"ר יב יד): מחשבה ביום, המעשה עם דמדומי חמה. והוא להורות על דבר מחושב, שיש בו טעם, לא חפץ פשוט בלבד: ומלת הויה מורה על מעשה הזמן העומד, כמו ואתה הוה להם למלך (נחמיה ו ו). לכן אמר הכתוב, כי כשברא חומר השמים, אמר שיהיה מן החומר ההוא דבר מזהיר קראו אור: ויהי אור - לא אמר "ויהי כן", כאמור בשאר הימים, לפי שלא עמד האור בתכונה הזאת כל הימים כשאר מעשה בראשית. ויש לרבותינו בזה מדרש בסוד נעלם. ודע, כי הימים הנזכרים במעשה בראשית היו בבריאת השמים והארץ ימים ממש, מחוברים משעות ורגעים, והיו ששה כששת ימי המעשה, כפשוטו של מקרא: ובפנימיות העניין יקראו "ימים" הספירות האצולות מעליון, כי כל מאמר פועל הוויה תקרא "יום". והיו ששה, כי לה' הגדולה והגבורה, והמאמרים עשרה, כי הראשונות אין שם "יום" נתפס בהם. והפירוש בסדור הכתובים בזה נשגב ונעלם, ודעתנו בו פחות מטפה מן הים הגדול:

(ד) וירא אלוהים את האור כי טוב - כתב רבנו שלמה: אף בזה אנו צריכין לדברי אגדה, ראה שאינו ראוי להשתמש בו רשעים והבדילו לצדיקים לעתיד לבוא. ולפי פשוטו כך פרשהו, ראהו כי טוב ואין נאה לו ולחשך להשתמש בערבוביא, וקבע לזה תחומו ביום ולזה תחומו בלילה. ורבי אברהם אמר: וירא, כמו וראיתי אני (קהלת ב יג), והיא במחשבת הלב. וטעם "ויבדל", בקריאת השמות: ואין דברי שניהם נכונים, שאם כן יראה כעניין המלכה ועצה חדשה, שיאמר כי אחרי שאמר אלוהים יהי אור, והיה אור, ראה אותו כי טוב הוא, ולכן הבדיל בינו ובין החשך, כעניין באדם שלא ידע טיבו של דבר עד היותו: אבל הסדר במעשה בראשית, כי הוצאת הדברים אל הפועל יקרא "אמירה"; ויאמר אלוהים יהי אור, ויאמר יהי רקיע, ויאמר תדשא הארץ. וקיומם יקרא "ראיה", כעניין וראיתי אני דקהלת (ב יג), וכן ותירא האשה כי טוב העץ למאכל (להלן ג ו), והוא כעניין שאמרו (כתובות קט א): רואה אני את דברי אדמון. וכמוהו (ש"ב טו כז): ויאמר המלך אל צדוק הכהן הרואה אתה שובה העיר בשלום. והעניין להורות כי עמידתם בחפצו, ואם החפץ יתפרד רגע מהם יהיו לאין. וכאשר אמר בכל מעשה יום ויום וירא אלוהים כי טוב, ובשישי כאשר נשלם הכל וירא אלוהים את כל אשר עשה והנה טוב מאד, כן אמר ביום הראשון בהיות האור וירא אלוהים כי טוב, שרצה בקיומו לעד: והוסיף בכאן "את האור", שאילו אמר סתם "וירא אלוהים כי טוב", היה חוזר על בריאת השמים והארץ, ולא גזר בהן עדיין הקיום, כי לא עמדו ככה, אבל מן החומר הנברא בראשון נעשה בשני רקיע, ובשלישי נפרדו המים והעפר ונעשית היבשה שקראה "ארץ", ואז גזר בהם הקיום, ואמר בהם: וירא אלוהים כי טוב: ויבדל אלוהים בין האור ובין החשך - איננו החשך הנזכר בפסוק הראשון שהוא האש, אבל הוא אפיסת האור, כי נתן אלוהים מידה לאור, שיהיה נעדר אחר כן עד שובו: ואמרו קצת המפרשים (כוזרי ב, כ): כי האור הזה נברא לפניו של הקב"ה, כלומר במערב, ושקעו מיד כדי מדת לילה, ואחרי כן האיר כמידת יום. וזה טעם ויהי ערב ויהי בקר, שקודם היה לילה ואחר כך יום, ושניהם אחרי הוויית האור. ואיננו נכון כלל, כי יוסיפו על ששת ימי בראשית יום קצר: אבל יתכן שנאמר, כי האור נברא לפניו יתברך ולא נתפשט ביסודות הנזכרים, והבדיל בינו ובין החשך שנתן לשניהם מידה, ועמד לפניו כמידת לילה, ואחר כך הזריח אותו על היסודות, והנה קדם הערב לבקר: ועוד יתכן שנאמר, כי משיצאו השמים והארץ מן האפס אל היש הנזכר בפסוק הראשון, נהיה זמן, כי אף על פי שזמנינו ברגעים ושעות שהם באור ובחשך, משיהיה יש ייתפש בו זמן. ואם כן נבראו שמים וארץ ועמדו כן כמידת לילה מבלי אור, ואמר יהי אור ויהי אור, וגזר עליו שיעמוד כמידת הראשון, ואחר כך יעדר מן היסודות, ויהי ערב ויהי בקר:

\end{document}
```

Any explanation of what went wrong?
Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: I’m not at all familiar with right-to-left-text, but does change anything, if you interchange the values of left- and rightskip? Means `\leftskip=0cm plus -0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus 0.5fil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As **Speravir** mentioned in a comment, interchanging the values for `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`, as in

```
\leftskip=0cm plus -0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus 0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
```

produces the desired result. Another option is to replace

```
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
```

with

```
\parfillskip=0cm plus -1fil
```

as in

```
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus -1fil
```

A complete example (I used a different font since I don't have `Narkisim`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,openany]{book}%Compile with xelatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Narkisim}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}
\newlength\iiindent \setlength\iiindent{15pt} 
\newcommand\secindent{\parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth } 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus -1fil
\sloppy
\everypar{\secindent}
(ג) ויאמר אלוהים יהי אור - מלת "אמירה" בכאן להורות על החפץ, כדרך מה תאמר נפשך ואעשה לך (ש"א כ ד), מה תרצה ותחפוץ, וכן ותהי אשה לבן אדניך כאשר דבר ה' (להלן כד נא), כאשר רצה. כי כן הוא הרצון לפניו, או הוא כגון מחשבה, כמו: האומרה בלבבה (ישעיה מז ח). ואמרו אלופי יהודה בלבם (זכריה יב ה). והעניין לומר שלא היה בעמל. וכך קראו רבותינו לזה "מחשבה". אמרו (ב"ר יב יד): מחשבה ביום, המעשה עם דמדומי חמה. והוא להורות על דבר מחושב, שיש בו טעם, לא חפץ פשוט בלבד: ומלת הויה מורה על מעשה הזמן העומד, כמו ואתה הוה להם למלך (נחמיה ו ו). לכן אמר הכתוב, כי כשברא חומר השמים, אמר שיהיה מן החומר ההוא דבר מזהיר קראו אור: ויהי אור - לא אמר "ויהי כן", כאמור בשאר הימים, לפי שלא עמד האור בתכונה הזאת כל הימים כשאר מעשה בראשית. ויש לרבותינו בזה מדרש בסוד נעלם. ודע, כי הימים הנזכרים במעשה בראשית היו בבריאת השמים והארץ ימים ממש, מחוברים משעות ורגעים, והיו ששה כששת ימי המעשה, כפשוטו של מקרא: ובפנימיות העניין יקראו "ימים" הספירות האצולות מעליון, כי כל מאמר פועל הוויה תקרא "יום". והיו ששה, כי לה' הגדולה והגבורה, והמאמרים עשרה, כי הראשונות אין שם "יום" נתפס בהם. והפירוש בסדור הכתובים בזה נשגב ונעלם, ודעתנו בו פחות מטפה מן הים הגדול:

(ד) וירא אלוהים את האור כי טוב - כתב רבנו שלמה: אף בזה אנו צריכין לדברי אגדה, ראה שאינו ראוי להשתמש בו רשעים והבדילו לצדיקים לעתיד לבוא. ולפי פשוטו כך פרשהו, ראהו כי טוב ואין נאה לו ולחשך להשתמש בערבוביא, וקבע לזה תחומו ביום ולזה תחומו בלילה. ורבי אברהם אמר: וירא, כמו וראיתי אני (קהלת ב יג), והיא במחשבת הלב. וטעם "ויבדל", בקריאת השמות: ואין דברי שניהם נכונים, שאם כן יראה כעניין המלכה ועצה חדשה, שיאמר כי אחרי שאמר אלוהים יהי אור, והיה אור, ראה אותו כי טוב הוא, ולכן הבדיל בינו ובין החשך, כעניין באדם שלא ידע טיבו של דבר עד היותו: אבל הסדר במעשה בראשית, כי הוצאת הדברים אל הפועל יקרא "אמירה"; ויאמר אלוהים יהי אור, ויאמר יהי רקיע, ויאמר תדשא הארץ. וקיומם יקרא "ראיה", כעניין וראיתי אני דקהלת (ב יג), וכן ותירא האשה כי טוב העץ למאכל (להלן ג ו), והוא כעניין שאמרו (כתובות קט א): רואה אני את דברי אדמון. וכמוהו (ש"ב טו כז): ויאמר המלך אל צדוק הכהן הרואה אתה שובה העיר בשלום. והעניין להורות כי עמידתם בחפצו, ואם החפץ יתפרד רגע מהם יהיו לאין. וכאשר אמר בכל מעשה יום ויום וירא אלוהים כי טוב, ובשישי כאשר נשלם הכל וירא אלוהים את כל אשר עשה והנה טוב מאד, כן אמר ביום הראשון בהיות האור וירא אלוהים כי טוב, שרצה בקיומו לעד: והוסיף בכאן "את האור", שאילו אמר סתם "וירא אלוהים כי טוב", היה חוזר על בריאת השמים והארץ, ולא גזר בהן עדיין הקיום, כי לא עמדו ככה, אבל מן החומר הנברא בראשון נעשה בשני רקיע, ובשלישי נפרדו המים והעפר ונעשית היבשה שקראה "ארץ", ואז גזר בהם הקיום, ואמר בהם: וירא אלוהים כי טוב: ויבדל אלוהים בין האור ובין החשך - איננו החשך הנזכר בפסוק הראשון שהוא האש, אבל הוא אפיסת האור, כי נתן אלוהים מידה לאור, שיהיה נעדר אחר כן עד שובו: ואמרו קצת המפרשים (כוזרי ב, כ): כי האור הזה נברא לפניו של הקב"ה, כלומר במערב, ושקעו מיד כדי מדת לילה, ואחרי כן האיר כמידת יום. וזה טעם ויהי ערב ויהי בקר, שקודם היה לילה ואחר כך יום, ושניהם אחרי הוויית האור. ואיננו נכון כלל, כי יוסיפו על ששת ימי בראשית יום קצר: אבל יתכן שנאמר, כי האור נברא לפניו יתברך ולא נתפשט ביסודות הנזכרים, והבדיל בינו ובין החשך שנתן לשניהם מידה, ועמד לפניו כמידת לילה, ואחר כך הזריח אותו על היסודות, והנה קדם הערב לבקר: ועוד יתכן שנאמר, כי משיצאו השמים והארץ מן האפס אל היש הנזכר בפסוק הראשון, נהיה זמן, כי אף על פי שזמנינו ברגעים ושעות שהם באור ובחשך, משיהיה יש ייתפש בו זמן. ואם כן נבראו שמים וארץ ועמדו כן כמידת לילה מבלי אור, ואמר יהי אור ויהי אור, וגזר עליו שיעמוד כמידת הראשון, ואחר כך יעדר מן היסודות, ויהי ערב ויהי בקר:

\end{document}
```

Am image of the final page showing the last line centered:

[image]

Comment: @Speravir if you want to post the answer with your suggestion, go ahead. I can delete mine.

Comment: A good reference here would be [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) (section **18.3.1 Centred last lines**, p 172).

Comment: Would there be anything else I would need to look out for with using Right-to-Left text?