# Looking for an Efficient Way to Center the Last Line of the Contents of a Minipage

Tags: minipage, alignment, center

Consider the code:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\textit{Objective:} Though All the Lines (Except the Last) in This Paragraph (Which is to Serve as a Title) are Both Left and Right Justified, I Would Like the Last Line of a Paragraph of This Sort to Always be ``Centered''}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

I would like to center the last line of the text, which keeping the right and left justification of the previous lines. So, I modified the above code by

```
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\textit{Objective:} Though All the Lines (Except the Last) in This Paragraph (Which is to Serve as a Title) are Both Left and Right Justified, I Would Like the Last Line of a Paragraph of This Sort to Always be \vskip 1pt \hfill \hskip 12pt ``Centered'' \hfill}
\end{minipage}
```

which produces:

[image]

Finally, this modification

```
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\textit{Objective:} Though All the Lines (Except the Last) in This Paragraph (Which is to Serve as a Title) are Both Left and Right Justified, I Would Like the Last Line of a Paragraph \hfill of \hfill This \hfill Sort \hfill to \hfill Always \hfill be \vskip 1pt \hfill \hskip 12pt ``Centered'' \hfill}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
```

produces what I am looking for:

[image]

As one can see, there is a lot of ``forcing'' taking place to accomplish this task.

QUESTION: Is there a more (most) efficient way to produce the output I am looking for without continually having to make manual adjustments. Is there a way to accomplish this automatically in Latex? I tend to produce many ``titles'' of this type in documents and am looking for a way to do this efficiently.

Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99364/how-to-center-the-last-line-of-a-paragraph

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes; thank you, but I am working with minipage environment---the posting you provide does not.

Comment: sure but minipage is not relevent to the question, tex's paragraph line breaker is the same in minipage or table p columns or on the main page, so you can use the same parameters to control the last line. Just as if the question had been "how do I get italic in a minipage" the answer `\itshape` wouldn't actualy depend on it being in minipage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line breaking algorithm is the same for any paragraph, whether or not in a `minipage` you can balance `\leftskip` and `\rightskip+\parfillskip` so the last line is centred.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\textit{Objective:} Though All the Lines (Except the Last) in This Paragraph (Which is to Serve as a Title) are Both Left and Right Justified, I Would Like the Last Line of a Paragraph of This Sort to Always be ``Centered''}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```