# \centerline ignores page margin

Tags: margins

I have the following page which I am trying to get the first line to be centered without affecting the other text. However, using `\centerline{}` seems to ignore the page margin and does not wrap text to fit the original margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\textbf{\large{Appendix \hypertarget{Appendix}{F}: Construction of the Managerial Performance Indicator (MSI)}}}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

This text is just for the example
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `\centerline` is not supported in LaTeX, …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The macro `\centerline` comes from Plain TeX and its behavior is exactly what you see: it centers without wrapping text and without respecting the margin.

The macro is not supported in LaTeX; it exists just for historical reasons. If one knows how to properly use it, well; otherwise, it's better to leave it alone.

Perhaps you are looking for

```
\begin{center}
\bfseries\large
Appendix \hypertarget{Appendix}{F}: Construction of the 
Managerial Performance Indicator (MSI)
\end{center}
```

#### Technical note.

Here is the definition of `\centerline`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 5030:
\def\centerline#1{\@@line{\hss#1\hss}}
```

and here is the definition of `\@@line`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 5027:
\def\@@line{\hb@xt@\hsize}
```

Oh, well, what's `\hb@xt@`?

```
% latex.ltx, line 784:
\def\hb@xt@{\hbox to}
```

So `\centerline{text}` is the same as typing

```
\hbox to \hsize{\hss text\hss}
```

which has some peculiar properties:

1. It doesn't start horizontal mode
2. The text inside is not wrapped
3. If the text inside is wider than `\hsize` (the current width for typesetting paragraphs), it will stick out in the margins by the same amount at left and right.