# What's wrong with \centerline{}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, best-practices

I'm pretty new to LaTeX/TikZ, and I've noticed that `\centerline{}` isn't really liked, and it's generally preferred to use `\centering`. However, I'm not sure I get this, because in my own programs, sometimes `\centering` won't work as I want it too, but `\centerline{}` always does, and I don't see any disadvantages to it. What is wrong with `centerline{}` (or alternatively, what is better about `\centering`)?

Comment: @egreg, what exactly do you mean? how does it behave differently? Also, my question is about `\centerline{}`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Does the answer to this question answer your question? [\centerline ignores page margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311293)

Comment: Mostly, yes. Thank you! I marked my question as a duplicate. I didn't find that question searching.