# Space between mdframed text and chessboard / chess line

Tags: mdframed, chess, xskak, chessboard

I have the following type of document, where I want to display some framed chess game header and continue with either a line or a chessboard:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[linewidth=1pt]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
{\centering
1. \textsc{Player 1 -- Player 2}\\
Testland \textbf{2018}\\}
\end{mdframed}
\begin{center}
\chessboard[addfen=K7/6RR/8/2k5/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{center}

\begin{mdframed}
{\centering
1. \textsc{Player 1 -- Player 2}\\
Testland \textbf{2018}\\}
\end{mdframed}

\newgame
\mainline[level=1]{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. d3 d6 6. Bg5 Na5}

\end{document}
```

However, the space between chessboard and header is quite large, while the space between the line and the header is good (far smaller). I fiddled around with several other solutions (like hrule and so on), but I can't solve this one. Actually it looks to me like twice the space between two paragraphs.

[image: Example document]

Comment: The center  environment introduce spaces

Comment: thank you :-) stupid me, using \centerline{\chessboard...} does the job, I also tested {\centering\chessboard...}, but this causes other problems like centering the text above.

Comment: `\centering` is better, but you need to ensure that you have a paragraph: `{\par\centering \chessboard \par}`.

Comment: OK :-) Is there a quick answer why centering is better than the centerline solution? or is centering just better than the center environment?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311293/2388

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for pointing the problem out. A combination of using \centering instead of the center environment and setting margintop=false in the chessboard options does the trick.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[linewidth=1pt]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
{\centering
1. \textsc{Player 1 -- Player 2}\\
Testland \textbf{2018}\\}
\end{mdframed}
{\par\centering \chessboard[addfen=K7/6RR/8/2k5/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1,margintop=false] \par}

\begin{mdframed}
{\centering
1. \textsc{Player 1 -- Player 2}\\
Testland \textbf{2018}\\}
\end{mdframed}

\newgame
\mainline[level=1]{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. d3 d6 6. Bg5 Na5}

\end{document}
```